# Cannot serve file with send_from_directory

Tags: python

When i try to server a file to a user requesting it with the following function:

```
# Prepare selected file for download...
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'
send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )
```

i get error:

```
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Why instead of serving the file the error mentions proxy or bad request?
The script is a mod_wsgi script with Directive 
`WSGIPassAuthorization On`enabled in httpd.conf

Comment: do you initialize filename?  Does webserver process have access to that folder?

Comment: Yes, the filename value is correct. How do i check tha latter?

Comment: I came to realize that it was due to the filenames containing a mix of latin+greek cjaracters that gave this "Bad Request Error". I turned the filename only to Greek letters and now it doesn't produce this error, but also it does NOT  send the file to the the users browser. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually i found it myself, i had to put it like this in order for pyhton to be able to  send the file `send_from_directory( filepath, filename)` Problem now is that if my filanme has greek letters iwhtin i still get `bad request`. Why is that?